Toast not displayed on the same layer as modal
I'm using daisyUI to create a modal like this:
<dialog id="importModal" className="modal z-0">
        <div className="modal-box z-0">
          <h3 className="font-bold text-lg">Test</h3>
          <div className="col-span-2 flex justify-end">
            <button className="btn btn-success" onClick={importHandler}>
              <Plus></Plus>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div className="modal-action">
            <form method="dialog">
              <button className="btn btn-error">Close</button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </dialog>

In the importHandler function, I'm doing this:
toast.error("Please enter a correct address", {
        style: {
          zIndex: 9999,
        },
});

In the root component, I have the following:
export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode;
}>) {
  return (
    <html lang="en" data-theme="synthwave">
      <body
        className={`${geistSans.variable} ${geistMono.variable} antialiased`}
      >
        <ToastContainer
          className="z-[9999]"
          position="bottom-right"
          style={{ fontSize: "14px", zIndex: 99999 }}
          autoClose={5000}
          hideProgressBar={false}
          newestOnTop={false}
          closeOnClick={false}
          rtl={false}
          pauseOnFocusLoss
          draggable
          pauseOnHover
          theme="dark"
          transition={Bounce}
        />
        {children}
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}

Why is the toast not displayed on the same layer as the modal, but in the background?
